# Android - The function getLayoutResource()?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-view

I saw this some code :

```
    ....
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResource() {
        return R.layout.activity_home;
    }
    ....
```

In which they used `getLayoutResource()` instead of `setContentView` in order to add `View Layout`.
I don't understand, why it is so. Does `getLayoutResource()` before or alongside with `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.
I read some about `getLayoutResource()` (Gets the layout resource that will be shown as the View for this Preference.) in [android developer document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#getLayoutResource())  but i didn't understand .

Is there anyone to explain more.

I want to know where and where we should use `getLayoutResource()`.

Comment: This is just a guess, perhaps the `getLayoutResource()` normally returns a variable that points at the layout (which is changed when u do `setContentView(int)` ) so when u override it you always return a specific layout that cannot be changed even if you use `setContent(int)` with another layout. I can't imagine this helping you with anyway and the extra function eats a little more memory, I believe `setContentView(int)` is better.

Comment: It's just there to avoid code repetition, it sounds wierd at first, but check the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32367041/calling-toolbar-on-each-activity

Answer (score 1):

While I can't tell from your code snippet, I don't think that you are talking about Preference, since Preferences don't have onCreate (as far as I know).  So, I am assuming that you are talking about a custom method named getLayoutResource in an activity.  As such, getLayoutResource likely just returns the layout resource ID, without doing anything to it. The returned layout resource ID could then be used in onCreate by setContentView, which actually inflates the resource.  We use it this way:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity {
    @Override
    onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        setContentView(getLayoutResource);
    }

    protected abstract int getLayoutResource();
}

public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResource() {
        return R.layout.my_activity_layout;
    }
}
```

In short, you use getLayoutResource anywhere where you need the layout resource ID for a view.

To read more about setContentView, check out this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView .

This answer discusses the difference between getLayoutResource and setContentView: [What is the different between setContentView and getLayoutResource in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38826131/what-is-the-different-between-setcontentview-and-getlayoutresource-in-android)