# Calling Toolbar on each Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-toolbar

My app has a toolbar that should be present on every view. Currently, I do the following in my `onCreate()` method for each Activity I have:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Does this need to be done in every `onCreate()` method in every Activity or is there a simpler way? Also, as a side question, how can I implement a "back" feature in the toolbar that takes the user back one action if they click it?

Comment: Yes, it is required.. If you using fragments & activity combination means one tool bar will do the work which present in the base activity

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Create a Base class for `Activity`**

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  Toolbar toolbar;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getLayoutResource());
    configureToolbar();
  }

  protected abstract int getLayoutResource();

  private void configureToolbar() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
      setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case android.R.id.home:
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fm != null && fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
          fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        } else {
          finish();
        }
        return true;
      default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  }
}
```

**And in each `Activity` extends this `BaseActivity` to get the `ToolBar` and implementing the back feature.**

**At last don't forget to include the `ToolBar` in each activity `layout`.**

**Edit:**

Override that method `getLayoutResource()` in each `Activity` and pass the layout id.

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Override
  public int getLayoutResource() {
    return R.layout.activity_main;
  }
```

Comment: @user5294977 see my edit.. You need to override getLayoutResource() in each method and return the layout id in this.

Comment: Can I add `getLayoutResource()` to BaseActivity so I don't have to put the method in every Activity?

Answer (score 2):

This is my implementation. It removes the need of the getLayoutResources() from the accepted answer and brings back the "setContentView()" in all activities as normal

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    protected boolean useToolbar() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, null);
        configureToolbar(view);
        super.setContentView(view);
    }

    private void configureToolbar(View view) {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            if (useToolbar()) {
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            } else {
                toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From here on you just extend BaseActivity. If you don't want a toolbar you will have to override the useToolbar().

Don't forget to add in activity.xml at the top

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</merge>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have used `Activity` then Create `BaseActivity` that extends `AppCompatActivity` or `ActionBarActivity`(Deprecated) and move `Toolbar` code to `BaseActivity`.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

If you have used `Fragment` then Create `BaseFragment` that extends `Fragment` and move `Toolbar` code to `BaseFragment`.

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

   View main;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) main.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        getActivity().setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        return main;
    }
}
```

In `main` XML layout you have to add `Toolbar` xml code.

Now in every view(Activity) extends `BaseActivity` instead of `AppCompatActivity` or `ActionBarActivity` so you can get access `Toolbar` in every view.

```
public class YourActivity extends BaseActivity{
//your code
}
```

**EDIT1:**

**main.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:theme="@style/toolbarTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT2:**

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

add these two lines below `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` in `BaseActivity`.

I hope it helps!

Comment: What is `R.layout.main` referring to?

Comment: Weird. The toolbar loads but the text/icons in the toolbar don't.

Comment: It's not showing anything, it's just a blank toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your implementation but if you want avoid boilerplate code you should use good programming OO.

An Example using Fragment.

```
public abstract class FragmentBase extends Fragment {

    protected void settingsToolbar(View rootView) {

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            // TODO add your code and your requirements
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        }
    }




}
```

I hope this can give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Create a base activity and initialize your tool bar in this class. Now it can be extends to all other child activity.

```
FirtActivity extends BaseActivity

SecondActivity extends BaseActivity
```

In base activity toll bar back button click you can check like below mentioned way

```
if(this instance of FirstActivity){
  //do stuff here
}else if(this instance of SecondActivity){
 //do stuff here
}
```