# What is the different between setContentView and getLayoutResource in android?

Tags: android, setcontentview

Generally, when we want to load android layout we use `setContentView(view)` in **onCreate** function. I saw another function `getLayoutResource()` which get load layout too. I have read [getLayoutResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#getLayoutResource()), but I don't understand about it.

### What is the different between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure where you read about `getLayoutResource()` as loading layout too? The `getLayoutResource()` method **gets the layout resource** that will be shown as the View. The `setContentView(view)` on the other hand **sets the activity content from a layout resource**. The resource will be inflated, adding all top-level views to the activity.

So for instance, if you had invoked `setContentView(R.layout.my_awesome_layout);`, then calling `getLayoutResource()` should return the Integer identifier for `R.layout.my_awesome_layout`;

You can read more on [setContentView(android.view.View)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View))

I hope this helps.